# JQuery confirmation dialogue box not calling proper function

Tags: jquery

I have used JQuery dialogue box which contains Yes-No button. Click on 'No' closes dialogue box. On clicking 'Yes' it should perform btnSubmit click event which tends to redirect to another page. But it some times happens that the dialogue gets closed but it reloads same page rather than redirecting. My code is as follows:

```
jqueryConfirmDialog = (function (dialogType, titleMsg) {
    $(".divConfirm").dialog({
        title: titleMsg,
        resizable: false,
        height: "auto",
        width: "auto",
        modal: true,
        dialogClass: dialogType,
        position: { my: "center", at: "center", of: window },
        buttons: {
            "Yes": function () {
                $(this).dialog('close');
                btnSubmit_click(true);
            },
            "No": function () {
                $(this).dialog('close');
            }
        }

    });
});
```

What could be the reason for this?

Comment: can u show the `btnSubmit_click()` function ?

Comment: sorry it is "$('form#paymentForm').submit();" instead of "btnSubmit_click(true);"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

according to jquery UI Dialog doc, your dialog buttons definition is wrong :

Try :

```
$(".divConfirm").dialog({
    [...]
    buttons: [
        {
            text: "Yes",
            click: function() {
                $(this).dialog('close');
                btnSubmit_click(true);
            }
        },
        {
            text: "No",
            click: function() {
                $(this).dialog('close');
            }
        }
    ]
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply VaN. I got this issue on customer's PC so will have to test it on that PC.. Hope it works well..